# Using char.sub command on multiple variables

Tags: spss

I have to select group of cases starting with specific numbers in multiple variables.

I am using this 
`CHAR.SUBSTR(variable1,1,x) ="y" | CHAR.SUBSTR(variable2,1,x) ="y" .............| CHAR.SUBSTR(variable40,1,x) ="y".`

(x is number of character,y is characters I am choosing) the variables are named similar with just the number 1 to 40 being different

it works but problem is there are 40 variables and code is very length.
any elegant way to write it? like variable1 THRU variable 40?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the variables and then select. Like this:

```
do repeat vr=variable1 to variable40.
  if CHAR.SUBSTR(vr,1,1)="y" keep_this=1.
end repeat.
select if keep_this=1.
```

after running the loop, if any of the variables starts with "y" then the line will be marked with 1 in the variable `keep_this`. Now you can select only cases where `keep_this=1`.